# python how do I paste non alphanumeric string in a excel cell

Tags: python, win32com

I want to put the below formula in one of the excel cells (A18), so that it links to a file and the excel performs some indirect vlookup function etc(which is not part of my problem here).

Problem is am struggling to paste it using python code. It should be pasted exactly in the below format else it wont work for me. How can I solve this problem?

```
="'W:\XYZ\ABC\DEF\"
```

Below is what I have tried and it didn't work for me

```
xlapp = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(filepath, None, False)
ws = wb.sheets['TT1']
ws.Range('A18').value = '=' + '"' + "'W:\\XYZ\\ABC\\DEF\\"
```

Below is the error message I'm getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ABC/PycharmProjects/PA/excel_copyTab.py", line 126, in <module>
    pastelink()
  File "C:/Users/ABC/PycharmProjects/PA/excel_copyTab.py", line 121, in pastelink
    ws.Range('A18').value = '=' + '"' + "'W:\\XYZ\\ABC\\DEF\\"
  File "C:\Users\ABC\Anaconda3\envs\PA36\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 581, in __setattr__
    raise AttributeError("Property '%s.%s' can not be set." % (self._username_, attr))
AttributeError: Property 'Range.value' can not be set.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
ws.Range('A18').value = '=' + '''"W:\XYZ\ABC\DEF\\"'''
FileName=ws.Range('A18').value+ws.Range('B10').value
print(FileName)
```

Comment: thanks @Sherin Jayanand, that worked only issue is I have a folder name saved on cell B10, which is 20190531\ ….. if I tried your formula and concatenated that folder I get error again. so my code is  ws.Range('A18').value = '=' + '''"'W:\XYZ\ABC\DEF\"''' + ws.Range('B10').value.

Comment: I have updated the code. See if it works now. Also you might want to update the value in B10 with an extra "\" i.e. it should be '20190531\\'. "\" is being treated as an escape character, hence the issue

Comment: no didn't work. I think something to do with the folder address in cell B10....  20190531\

Comment: anyways appreciate your help with the original problem

Comment: If this is what you want `W:\XYZ\ABC\DEF\20190531\`, I have an updated code. Let me know and I can update it for you.

Comment: Please check the updated code now. I have used print to show you the output but you can use it any way you want. I just removed single quote right before "W:", you did not need it for what you wanted to achieve. Hope this solves your issue.